# Typeorm merge entities

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a one-to-one relation. There is *always* one Product and one Stock entity in tables which are interconnected.

I'm trying to achieve an object of one level depth instead of Stock with nested Product in `product` property.

```js
@Entity('products')
export class ProductEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 255,
        nullable: false
    })
    title: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 1000
    })
    description: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'integer',
    })
    price: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 500
    })
    imgSrc: string;
}

@Entity('stocks')
export class StockEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => ProductEntity)
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'product_id',
        referencedColumnName: 'id'
    })
    product: ProductEntity;

    @Column({
        type: 'integer'
    })
    count: number;
}
```

I expect resulting object to be a simple object with properties `id`, `title`, `description`, `price`, `imgSrc`, `count`.

I have tried `leftJoinAndSelect` however it made an object with `count` and `product` properties. The latter one containing the row from Products table.

So far I managed to achieve it by writing a regular SQL query, however I suspect that this isn't a good approach as I'm using ORM and the task I'm trying to accomplish should be achievable by the ORM tools.

My SQL query is following

```js
connection.query('SELECT products.id id, title, description, price, img_src imgSrc, count FROM products RIGHT JOIN stocks ON stocks.product_id = products.id')
```

How can I achieve the same result using `typeorm`'s capabilities?

Comment: Have you explored the `getRawMany` method of query builder?